# protractor - timing (sleep, wait etc.)

Tags: protractor, performance-testing, angularjs-e2e

I have two questions regarding the whole timing issue with protractor:

1. I noticed that I still have to use browser.sleep() although protractor should implicitly do it. am I doing something wrong? and how is it related to 'rowser.ignoreSynchronization = true;' and none angular pages?
2. can I actually measure the testing times and use it as performance tests? or does protractor increase the actual time?

thanks.

Comment: Could you provide some code snippets causing this behavior?